# Texturing a sphere in iphone's OpenGL ES

Tags: iphone

Basically i want a 3d rotating earth. gluSphere function isn't found. is it available on the iphone's opengl es? how can i render a sphere otherwise?

Answer (score 4):

No GLUT for the iPhone, but [this](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/procedural-spheres-in-opengl-es.html) may be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Procedural sphere will not be much helpful when you also want to texture it, I suggest you to use one of the many rendering libraries and a model with proper uv map.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be helpful... I'm using procedural spheres that I'm texturing, I only have to generate UVs when I'm generating vertices and normals.